# USB camera synchronization with external trigger

Tags: usb, camera

My project is to synchronize 4 usb cameras using a raspberry pi. Those 4 cameras use 8MP sensors, the SPCA2620 chip (quite new, no documentation) and have an external trigger line available.

So far, I have plugged all 4 cameras, linked all the triggers together. The trigger pin on the camera board is pulled up to Vcc, a grounded line takes the shot (not tested).

I am not interested in video streaming; my guess is that 4 cameras on the RPi usb hub won’t allow a high framerate anyway. The idea is to synchronize the frames using that external trigger, driven by the RPi, and grab all 4 at once.

What would be the way to go?
Thank you for your help.